# Check if a word can be created from a random letter string using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, cpu-word, letter

```
<?php
    $randomstring = 'raabccdegep';
    $arraylist = array("car", "egg", "total");
?>
```

Above `$randomstring`  is a string which contain some alphabet letters.
And I Have an Array called `$arraylist` which Contain 3 Words Such as `'car' , 'egg' , 'total'`.

Now I need to check the string Using the words in array and print if the word can be created using the string.
For Example I need an Output Like.

```
car is possible.
egg is not possible.
total is not possible.
```

Also Please Check the repetition of letter. ie, `beep` is also possible. Because the string contains two `e`. But `egg` is not possible because there is only one `g`.

Comment: Does the character falls down once it's used on the verification string ? e.g we search car and verification string is "thecar" (car found then verification string is now )-> "the"?

Comment: No. Can Be Reused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function find_in( $haystack, $item ) {
    $match = '';
    foreach( str_split( $item ) as $char ) {
        if ( strpos( $haystack, $char ) !== false ) {
            $haystack = substr_replace( $haystack, '', strpos( $haystack, $char ), 1 );
            $match .= $char;
        }
    }
    return $match === $item;
}

$randomstring = 'raabccdegep';
$arraylist = array( "beep", "car", "egg", "total");

foreach ( $arraylist as $item ) {
    echo find_in( $randomstring, $item ) ? " $item found in $randomstring." : " $item not found in $randomstring.";
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Last 3 lines Should be in a foreach loop of $arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
        $randomstring = 'raabccdegep';
        $arraylist = array("car", "egg", "total");

        foreach($arraylist as $word){
            $checkstring = $randomstring;
            $beMade = true;
            for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++ ) {
                $char = substr( $word, $i, 1 );
                $pos = strpos($checkstring, $char);
                if($pos === false){
                    $beMade = false;
                } else {
                    substr_replace($checkstring, '', $i, 1);    
                }
            }
            if ($beMade){
                echo $word . " is possible \n";
            } else {
                echo $word . " is not possible \n";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: When I Tried this. I have got 'egg is possible'. But as my need The word 'egg' shouldnt be possible.